# CodeMirror: Particular lines readonly

Tags: javascript, codemirror

Can I set a particular number of lines (sucessive or not) to read-only mode?

For example: I have a document where I don't want the contents of some sections to be changed (like in Word, where you can set Header and Footer sections and you can lock them).
Anyone know if CodeMirror supports that feature?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With codemirror version 3 support for `on` and `beforeChange` was added; simply catching the change before it happens and canceling should do the trick:

```
// the line numbers to be "readonly"
var readOnlyLines = [0,1,2,3];

// create the CodeMirror instance
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('input'));

// listen for the beforeChange event, test the changed line number, and cancel
editor.on('beforeChange',function(cm,change) {
    if ( ~readOnlyLines.indexOf(change.from.line) ) {
        change.cancel();
    }
});
```

Comment: Pretty straight forward! I've just added some minor tweaks in order to still be able to delete the content between two non consecutive lines even if the user selects the read-only lines. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 18):

There is also `markText` with the `readOnly` option, which might map more directly to your use case. See http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#markText

Answer (score 0):

**For CodeMirror6**

I just released `codemirror-readonly-ranges` extension that easy allow to work with read-only ranges.
For anyone who is interested on the solution:

package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/codemirror-readonly-ranges

full documentation: https://andrebnassis.github.io/codemirror-readonly-ranges